# How to map an array of objects, return entire array with one altered

Tags: javascript

When I run the `decreaseQuantity()` function, I simply want to return the entire array of objects, but with the quantity of the one object altered (determined by passing the index, in this case "1", to the function).

Right now, I'm just returning the second Object (with the quantity correctly decreased by one), when I want to also have the first Object returned as well (unaltered). So I want to return the entire array of objects, but with the quantity altered for the specified object.

What am I doing incorrectly? Help appreciated.

```
let cars = 
    [
  {
  color: "red",
  type: "minivan",
  quantity: 7
},
  {
  color: "blue",
  type: "lambo",
  quantity: 5
}
]

    function decreaseQuantity(index) {
        if (cars[index]) {
          const updateCars = cars.map((product, i) => {
            if (index == i) return { ...product, quantity: product.quantity - 1};
          });
          return updateCars;
        }
    }

console.log(decreaseQuantity(1))
```

Comment: Can you post a example output ?

Comment: you just need to add `else return product;`

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `return product` for the else clause. Everything else is fine. You may try to run the code to my answer with the added `else` and see the console output for `cars` and `updateCars`.

```js
let cars = [
  {
    color: "red",
    type: "minivan",
    quantity: 7
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    type: "lambo",
    quantity: 5
  }
];

function decreaseQuantity(index) {
    if (cars[index]) {
      const updateCars = cars.map((product, i) => {
          if (index == i) {
            return { ...product, quantity: product.quantity - 1};
          } else {
            return product;
          }
      });
      return updateCars;
    }
}
const updateCars = decreaseQuantity(1);

console.log(cars);
console.log(updateCars);
```

Comment: Thanks, Ulrich, you were more attentive to the question than I was. Do not you think that you can remove the first condition because you have the second that performs the check?

Comment: i know what you are meaning :) i only wanted to change as little as possible on the original code... so i left it in

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it right:

```
cars.map((product, i) => {
    if (index == i) return { ...product, quantity: product.quantity - 1};
});
```

simply add `else return product`. Although I would recommend the ternary operator:

```
cars.map((product, i) => index === i ? { ...product, quantity: product.quantity - 1} : product;
```

Comment: yep you're currently only returning a value when the index matches in the map function

Answer (score 0):

```js
let cars = [{
    color: "red",
    type: "minivan",
    quantity: 7
}, {
    color: "blue",
    type: "lambo",
    quantity: 5
}]

function decreaseQuantity(index) {

    if (cars[index]) {
        cars[index].quantity -= 1;
    }

    return cars;

}

console.log(decreaseQuantity(0));
console.log(decreaseQuantity(1));
```

Note: With that, you change the original object.

Comment: I dont think he wants to change the original array. he wants to create a new one with just the one object modified. You can look at my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-minsky-k7b8z?file=/src/index.js:0-393) is the playground.

```js
const cars = [
  {
    color: "red",
    type: "minivan",
    quantity: 7
  },
  {
    color: "blue",
    type: "lambo",
    quantity: 5
  }
];

function decreaseQuantity(cars, index) {
  return cars.map((product, i) => {
    if (index === i) {
      return { ...product, quantity: product.quantity - 1 };
    } else {
      return product;
    }
  });
}

console.log(decreaseQuantity(cars, 0));
```

Comment: i dont think, that he wants to modify the original array

Comment: do you have a good link to documentation so I can learn more about modifying the original array? especially want to learn more about this part "{ ...product, quantity: product.quantity - 1 };"

Comment: If you wish we can have a chat or call and I can explain my understanding of this. What do you think @Alex? Skype, Telegram, Zoom?